# How can I write a PostgreSQL query using Sequel without raw SQL?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

My query, in raw SQL, is:

```
DB.fetch(' SELECT 
        p.project_name, 
        p.project_id,
        COUNT(i.expense_project_id) AS item_count,
        SUM(COALESCE(amount,0)) AS item_amount
 FROM expense_projects p 
 LEFT JOIN expense_items i ON p.project_id = i.expense_project_id      
 WHERE p.project_company_id = ?passed_param
 GROUP BY p.project_id, p.project_name').to_a.to_json
```

How can I write this query using the Sequel ORM?

I have since found a solution which is as follows. I had made multiple efforts before and I should have included one of my failed efforts when I posted this question, apologies! Answer here:

```
DB[:expense_projects___p].where(:project_company_id=>user_company_id).
  left_join(:expense_items___i, :expense_project_id=>:project_id).
  select_group(:p__project_name, :p__project_id).
  select_more{count(:i__item_id)}.
  select_more{sum(:i__amount)}.to_a.to_json
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's customary when asking a question concerning finding out how to do something, for you to supply at least one sample of the code you have tried and show why it doesn't meet your needs. Failing to do that makes it look like you haven't tried and only want someone to write it for you, which is not what we do here. I'd recommend adding your attempts to solve the problem to the question. In addition, have you asked this on the Sequel mail list or IRC channel?

Comment: thank you, yes I have made multiple attempts and I will post the closest version tomorrow. I understand your point and I apologize if I, unintentionally, appear to be abusing the community.

Comment: Ponder this: your query already works in SQL (a common, industry-standard language for interacting with your database) - does translating it into another domain-specific language improve the readability, performance, or maintainability of the code?

Comment: The advantage to using an ORM is it means the query becomes much more easily ported. The same logic will work on SQLite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. Pure SQL is portable, but most DBMs need vendor-specific extensions to do anything that takes advantage of the features of the DBM. Reducing as much of that vendor-specific code is a good thing. I use SQLite for local testing of ideas, and then step to PostgreSQL or MySQL on our dev/test hosts. We currently use PostgreSQL for our production systems, but it's nice that we could use the same code with an Oracle DB, without code changes.

Comment: @user1903663, please move your solution into an answer, rather than in your question. Stack Overflow will require a grace-period to expire before you can select the answer, but I'd recommend you do so as you found the solution.

Comment: @theTinMan so now your coupled to a non industry standard technology aka the ORM. I'm pretty sure it would be hard if not impossible to switch out your ORM. An enormous amount of SQL today is already portable across all the major databases. In fact the parts that are not portable are typically not supported by the ORM anyway (eg window functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB[:expense_projects___p].where(:project_company_id=>user_company_id).
  left_join(:expense_items___i, :expense_project_id=>:project_id).
  select_group(:p__project_name, :p__project_id).
  select_more{count(:i__item_id)}.
  select_more{sum(:i__amount)}.to_a.to_json
```